# In Trac, is there a way to globally reassign all of a given user's tickets to another user?

Tags: trac

The title pretty much sums up the question. One of our developers is leaving, and we would like to reassign all of his tickets. Is there a way to do it in the proverbial "one swell foop"? Or failing that, what would be the quickest, easiest way?

And if it's a matter of RTFM, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Trac has a [Batch modify](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBatchModify) feature for the query module. It was added in Trac 1.0. If you have an earlier version, there is [batch modify plugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BatchModifyPlugin).

The standard workflow only allows open tickets to be reassigned:

```
reassign = new,accepted,assigned,reopened -> assigned
reassign.operations = set_owner
reassign.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
```

To change the owner of closed tickets you may need another action:

```
set_owner = closed -> closed
set_owner.name = set owner
set_owner.operations = set_owner
set_owner.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
```

Comment: I'm looking at a query of all tickets with that user as owner, and I have "Batch Modify" open at the bottom of the page. But all I see are a text box for "Comment," a drop-down marked "Add Field," and an "Action" section, with radio buttons for "leave as closed" and "reopen." Nothing about reassigning ownership of the ticket.

Comment: You may need to modify your workflow. Or you may not have sufficient permissions, depending on your workflow. I updated my answer with one possibility. Please post your workflow to your question (if posted as a comment the formatting will not be good).